# What document should I use for RyanAir check in: non-EU passport or Spanish residency card?

Tags: visas, paperwork, check-in, ryanair, moroccan-citizens

I've booked a flight from Malaga to Ibiza. I'm Moroccan and only have a Moroccan passport. I'm going to be traveling with my Spanish residency card. However, the Ryanair system is asking me for my travel document.

What should I put: my passport or residency card? When I put in my nationality as a Moroccan, the only choice I have for document type is passport.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you have much of a choice at this point. Enter your nationality accurately, which means you will have to put in your passport information if that's what the system requires.

However, Ryanair requires that [all non-EU/EEA nationals visit a special document check counter at the airport before going through security](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/passports-and-visas/im-a-non-eu-eea-passenger-do-I-need-extra-travel-document-visa-check), where you'll present your travel documents (such as your Spanish residency card) and get a stamp. There are various reports of them being extremely strict about this fairly obscure requirement, denying boarding and forcing passengers to pay for new flights even if they didn't know this was required by Ryanair. So be sure to go to this desk and have your documents checked first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your passport number in that field, and at the airport, present both the boarding pass, passport and residence permit at the document check desk in order to get your boarding pass stamped.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably related to the [Advanced Passenger Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record).  However, you should check with your airline.

Comment: Except for not answering the question, I suppose you are referring to the Advance Passenger Information System (*Advance* - not Advance*d*), which is a programme operated by the US Customes and Border Protection and applies to passenger on flights bound for the US. It is hard to see how that can be relevant for a domestic Spanish flight.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo  Thought I was answering the question.  Did you not read the link I provided? OK, it might be known under a slightly different name, but the EU has a very similar system (which I have now learnt is called Passenger Name Record).  Also, I have been asked multiple times to provide passport information in advance of  flights within the EU, and at the time of my answer was unaware of Ryanair's specific visa check requirements for non-EU/EEA passengers.